# How do I require a gem for a gem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm making a gem (lets call it `stackoverflow`), and in order for it to work, I need to require another gem (lets say I need `typhoeus`) in the gems code. Do I need to do anything outside of the normal

```
require rubygems
require gemname

$code
```

Comment: Does my answer answer your question? Also, it should be noted that you're requiring 'rubygems'. I know this is somewhat pseudocode but you shouldn't require rubygems yourself

Comment: @injekt Yes, that was more of pseudocode - I don't normally require rubygems, I made a typo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Define it as a dependency in your `gemspec`. Check out the [Specification Reference](http://guides.rubygems.org/specification-reference/), or more specifically, [#add_runtime_dependency](http://guides.rubygems.org/specification-reference/#add_runtime_dependency) over at [RubyGems guides](http://guides.rubygems.org/) (Which is awesome, by the way). This ensures that your libraries dependencies will be installed along with your own gem.

Apart from that, just use `require` as you would have before. Happy hacking!